# How do I run a python file with arguments as variables from another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm working on cloning a Virtual Machine (VM) in vCenter environment using [this code](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/clone_vm.py). It takes command line arguments for name of the VM, template, datastore, etc. (e.g. `$ clone_vm.py -s <host_name> -p < password > -nossl ....`)

I have another Python file where I've been able to list the Datastore volumes in descending order of free_storage. I have stored the datastore with maximum available storage in a variable `ds_max`. (Let's call this ds_info.py)
I would like to use `ds_max` variable from `ds_info.py` as a command line argument for datastore command line argument in `clone_vm.py`.

I tried importing the os module in `ds_info.py` and running `os.system(python clone_vm.py ....arguments...)` but it did not take the `ds_max` variable as an argument.

I'm new to coding and am not confident to change the `clone_vm.py` to take in the Datastore with maximum free storage.
Thank you for taking the time to read through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is something wrong in your `os.system` call, but you don't provide it, so I can't check.

Generally it is a good idea to use the current paradigm, and the received wisdom (TM) is that we use `subprocess`.  See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), but the basic pattern is:

```py
from subprocess import run

cmd = ["mycmd", "--arg1", "--arg2", "val_for_arg2"]
run(cmd)
```

Since this is just a list, you can easily drop arguments into it:

```py
var = "hello"
cmd = ["echo", var]
run(cmd)
```

However, if your other command is in fact a *python* script it is more normal to refactor your script so that the main functionality is wrapped in a function, called `main` by convention:

```py
# script 2
...
def main(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    do_the_work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_sys_args() # dummy fn
    main(*args)
```

Then you can simply import `script2` from `script1` and run the code directly:

```py
# script 1
from script2 import main
args = get_args() # dummy fn
main(*args)
```

This is 'better' as it doesn't involve spawning a whole new python process just to run python code, and it generally results in neater code.  But nothing stops you calling a python script the same way you'd call anything else.